# IE9 Stops loading images after x images have loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

I am trying to create a virtual magazine line turnjs.com, I Purchesed the commerical version of the library, and all works well when I only have a few pages. But when I try to run the site with book that has 172 images 300 dpi 2550 x 3263 and sized down with CSS  IE stops loading the images after about 50.

I though it was a turn.js problem at first, so I stripped out all the turnjs code and wrote a simple js

```
$(window).load(function(){

    for(var i=0;i<ContentArray.length;i++){

        $("#content").append("<img src='" + ContentArray[i] + "' style='width:600px; height:600px'/>");

    }

});
```

Content Array is loaded from an ajax call and it just contains the paths to the images. When the code runs it loads the images up until about 50 or so then it just show the red x.

Now My question is, this works in Fire Fox and Chrome but not IE, is there a limit on how many image or better yet the size of the images IE loads. I am only targeting IE9.

Any help would be very greatly appreciated. and I know the Images are rather large, I need them to be this large to allow zooming.

---

- Check for new versions of stored pages : automatically
- Disk space to use: 300 MB
- Days to keep pages in history: 20

I thought it may have been my dev machine, but I have checked these settings and I tested this on two different PC's plus a freshly created windows 7 pro virtual Machine. What I have done is lower the DPI on the images, and it loaded more images, but still not all of them, then I lowered further down to 150 DPI and all of the images loaded, the problem with a dpi so low is the text in the images gets very pixelated, and zooming makes for a very unpleasent experiance.

Does anyone know what the limit on IE is when it comes to large images 300k to 500k in size. The only solution I have seen so far is to require my users to install ChromeFrame

Comment: Why do you need more than 4-8 images loaded at a time? If it's a virtual magazine,the most pages that will be visible at a time is 4, and 8 would allow for preloading 2 pages in each direction.

Comment: It sound like a memory limit (because more can be loaded at a smaller DPI) and not a count limit. How much memory is the process and/or cache using? It seems like resources could be better-utilized with a load-as-needed approach (e.g. Bing / Google Image Search) ..

Comment: The Turn.js Library I am using removes the images from the dom as you turn the pages, however there seems to be an array within the library itself that is holding on to the images and not releasing them, I have an email out with the author of turn am still waiting. But it does look like a DPI problem. Oh and the process starts out at about 21mb and as you turn the pages, we end up around 32 before it stops loading images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just ended up just lower the DPI to 150, the client seems to be ok with that.